# Php MySql friend request 0 row affected

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Guys i have problem when try to update col in table.

I have table where i store friend relationship and friend requests.

**Friend table looks like this:**

```
`friend_one` INT(11) ,
`friend_two` INT(11) ,
`status` ENUM('0','1','2') DEFAULT '0'
```

**I use the following insert statement for adding a friend.**

```
INSERT INTO friends
(friend_one,friend_two)
VALUES
('$user_id','$friend_id');
```

All that work fine but whan i try to confirm friend request to update status to 1 return me 0 row affected but query is successful.

**For confirm request :**

```
UPDATE friends
SET status="1"
WHERE
(friend_one="$user_id" OR friend_two="$user_id")
AND
(friend_one="$friend_id" OR friend_two="$friend_id");
```

And all time is the some:

> 1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings
>
> Query: UPDATE friends SET STATUS=1 WHERE (friend_one= 2 OR friend_two=
>   2) AND (friend_one=1 OR friend_two=1)
>
> 0 row(s) affected
>
> Execution Time : 0.037 sec Transfer Time  : 0 sec Total Time     :
>   0.038 sec

I have only one record in table but never change status to 1:

```
friend_one  friend_two  status  
----------  ----------  --------
         2           1  0
```

Comment: are you sure that is your php output UPDATE friends SET STATUS=1 WHERE (friend_one= 2 OR friend_two= 2) AND (friend_one=1 OR friend_two=1) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
UPDATE friends
SET status="1"
WHERE
(friend_one="$user_id" AND friend_two="$friend_id") // check the change in line
OR // replace AND with OR
(friend_one="$friend_id" AND friend_two="$user_id");// check the change in line
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `OR` operator instead of `AND`:

```
UPDATE friends
SET status="1"
WHERE
( (friend_one="$user_id" OR friend_two="$user_id")
OR
(friend_one="$friend_id" OR friend_two="$friend_id") );
```

Comment: it should update records where friend_one = 2 or 1 OR friend_two = 2 or 1

Comment: Yup i see my mistake! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think the better way to do this would be using unique friendship id's like:

```
friendship_id |  sender_id |    reciever_id |  status

         1           5         6         0
```

So when you send the confirm request the query would look like this

```
$sql="SELECT friendship_id from friends where sender_id='$sender' and reciever_id='$reciever' OR sender_id='$reciever' and reciever_id='$sender'";
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

---

And then you send this to the confirm script with this query

---

```
$confirm="UPDATE friends SET STATUS=0/1/2 where friendship_id='$row[friendship_id]'";
```

Hope this works! I'm open for discussion! Thanks!

Comment: Great! I thought i should just share my thoughts on this!

Answer (score 0):

Change OR operator instead of AND operator
Try this one.

```
UPDATE friends
SET status="1"
WHERE
(friend_one="$user_id" AND friend_two="$friend_id") // check the change in line
OR // replace AND with OR
(friend_one="$friend_id" AND friend_two="$user_id");// check the change in line
```